# Convert Facebook messenger attachment image-type to base64 in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, facebook, base64

I need to write some code that take an image url in Facebook messenger and convert it into image.

However, using image-to-base64 or fetch-base64 will not work, because the facebook payload url has timestamp at the end of it, while those tool require the url to end in .jpg or .png.

Url format:

```
https://scontent.fhan2-4.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-0/p480x480/60251115_627131164420267_474161086648549376_n.png?_nc_cat=100&_nc_oc=AQmldFK_xUgJPT-rqrk4bxLivk8ispusU5THY7br4ZpvNTfcYVrfU-rBFlIX9cwUzaw&_nc_ht=scontent.fhan2-4.fna&oh=140ea3424f8fa6a9085b3ae88281fa51&oe=5D5F4DAD
```

I have tried using image-to-base64 and fetch-base6, and neither of them works.

```
const image2base64 = require('image-to-base64');

module.exports = (string) => {
    console.log(string);
    image2base64(string) // you can also to use url
        .then(
            (response) => {

                console.log(response); 
            }
        )
        .catch(
            (error) => {
                console.log(error); 
            }
        )
}
```

I would like to get the base64 resul, so I wonder if there is any package that can help me with this task.

Comment: You could temporarily store the image first using Axios for example, and go from there.

Comment: Facebook doesn’t seem to mind if you append something like `&_foo=.jpg` at the end of the URL - maybe that could be enough already to “trick” these tools …?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the problem.

For anyone need to get the url of attachment in Facebook messenger, the form of:

```
message.attachments[0].payload
```

when represented as String is like this:

{"url":"**THE_URL_THAT_YOU_NEED**"}

So, to get **THE_URL_THAT_YOU_NEED**, you have to remove the string `{"url":"` and `"}` first, which can be done easily like this

```
var url= (JSON.stringify(event.message.attachments[0].payload).replace("{\"url\":\"","")).replace("\"}","");
```

Probably not the best solution, but works for me.